# nodemon not restarting after typescript change

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, nodemon

My nodemon is not restarting after a typescript file change.

Currently I'm using the following to run and compile my changes:

```
"dev": "nodemon -e ts,json --exec \"npm run compile\"",
"compile": "tsc && node src/index.js"
```

it should detect *ts* changes and recompile however it's not.

It is running through a docker container linked with a volume, the code in volume should be watched.

*docker-compose*

```
version: '2'
services:
  api:
    build:
      context: ./api
    ports: ["5000:5000"]
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
```

*the override:*

```
version: '2'
services:
  api:
    command: yarn run dev
    volumes:
      - ./api/src:/usr/workspace/api/src      
    environment:      
      - NODE_ENV=dev
```

The api has the following *dockerfile*

```
FROM node:latest

# Install yarn
RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - \
  && echo "deb http://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list  && apt-get update && apt-get clean

# Set working dir and copy contents of our images to that dir  
RUN mkdir -p /usr/workspace/api && cd /usr/workspace/api

# install dependencies
COPY *.json /usr/workspace/api/
WORKDIR /usr/workspace/api

# npm install will check NODE_ENV if its production if will not install dev dependencies
RUN npm install --silent && npm install -g nodemon pm2 typescript --silent

# copy sources
COPY ./src ./src

# create env file with the port
ENV PORT 8100
EXPOSE $PORT

CMD ["pm2-docker", "src/process.json"]
```

as you can see, with the override i run the development environment instead of staging

i have tried turning the watch option to true in my **tsconfig** however then the code doesn't re run. when i change the nodemon options to watch *js* files as well it works, however it then constantly rebuilds because it detects js files change when it compiles.

any opinions?

Comment: can you post more info, such as the `docker run` you are using, with volume mounts. having the `dockerfile` contents and knowing what the `CMD` and/or `ENTRYPOINT` are would help, too

Comment: Thank you for your remark, I have updated my original post with more details

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have fixed this issue by adding the `-L` switch to nodemon. this apparently uses the legacy watch which worked on the docker container

```
"dev": "nodemon -L -e ts,json --exec \"npm run compile\"",
```

Comment: fyi, for me, it was sufficient to add `-e ts`.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I did choose to also include json (or other files) as it is useful for my configuration files when i edit them

Comment: right -- sorry, I wasn't clear. For some reasons, just adding `-e` with a relevant option (for me, just ts) got my nodemon restarting. It was detecting the changes without `-e`, but when I added it, the restarts started happening. I think I misunderstood that nodemod would restart on any change without the option -- it looks like I had to explicitly tell it what I was interested in.

Comment: btw, your answer says you added the `-L` switch, but it doesn't show that in your code snippet.

Comment: Well spotted, Thank you, adjusted it!

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: the legacy swith is documented here: https://github.com/remy/nodemon#application-isnt-restarting if you have troubles with webpack or webpack dev server hot reloading you can pass the `CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING` as an environment variable which will make it fallback to that polling mechanism